# Ansible Tower: execute playbook in a different server

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

Can Ansible Tower execute playbooks in a different server (other than the server that it is installed) ?

Answer (score 0):

Please describe your question in more detail. I can only assume that you want to run your playbook via the tower in a different network that you can only access via ssh.

For that usecase you can use a bastion (read [this article](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/12/24/running-ansible-through-ssh-bastion-host/)). A bastion enables you to execute commands from your local machine on machines in another network via a jump host without the need to first log in to it.

But try it first with just an ansible -m ping or so before you try to configure your tower in a way that this works (but it should).

The configuration shouldn't be so hard when you read the article. Hope that was the target of your question.